# Creating a tab-delimited .txt table from an ArrayList<String> matrix

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, csv

I am currently working on the creation of a tab-delimited table for Excel from an `ArrayList<String>` matrix in Java.

The matrix is a `List<List<String>` and currently I am adding `"\t"` to every single String in the matrix and `"\n"` to the last elements of each row. I use `for` loops to do so.

For a 1500 x 3000 matrix this process takes an insane amount of time (120s).

What is a better way too approach this problem in order to cut down on time?

Comment: Please post the code you are using.  Are you using `+` to concatenate your strings?  `StringBuilder`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure which way your matrix is but could be built something like this I suppose. Dont see any obvious overhead here.

```
private final List<List<String>> matrix;
private final String SEPARATOR = "\t";
private final String END_OF_LINE = "\n";

public TSVFormatter(List<List<String>> matrix) {
    this.matrix = matrix;
}

public String doParse() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
        for (int o = 0; o < matrix.get(i).size(); o++) {
            sb.append(matrix.get(i).get(o));
            if (o <( matrix.get(i).size()-1))
                sb.append(SEPARATOR);
            else
                sb.append(END_OF_LINE);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I should have posted my code but it was practically identical to what you just posted. The difference: I constructed a single `String` for the `BufferedWriter` though iterating over all Strings in the matrix and concatenating the seperator. Using your approach has brought down the time from 120k milliseconds to 3k milliseconds and that is good enough for me at the moment. First tiem I learned about StringBuilder. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using `StringBuilder` is better to use when you have to concatenate in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringBuilder` to form the CSV records and then use `BufferedWriter` to write them to file. Using `BufferedWriter` would save content in buffer and do writes after buffer is full, thus avoiding continuous access to hard disk to write.

Post your code in order for us to be able to help in better way.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code it's hard to make any concrete suggestions, but you want to avoid generating the complete string to write (and all the associated memory allocations and garbage collections), and instead just walk the arrays, emitting a stream of strings, tabs and newlines to the file buffer.